# 2x2 matrix and convergence under iteration connected to eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When working with a general matrix $A=$ \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix},

I find that the eigenvalues are:

$\lambda = \frac{d+a \pm \sqrt{(d-a)^2+4bc}}{2}$

I then find that eigenvectors, $e=$ \begin{bmatrix}-b\\a-\lambda\end{bmatrix}.

I also know that under iteration with initial vector $x_n$ = \begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix},  we have $x_{n+1} = Ax_n$.

The matrix $A$ converges to a line with a slope $m$.   I am told that the slope of this line is in the same direction as the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue.   How do I prove this?

Comment: it is $(d-a)^2 + 4 b c,$ which is why it is certain to be positive when $a,b,c,d$ are all positive, which is the condition you should be mentioning. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron-Frobenius_eigenvector

Comment: @WillJagy you say "it is $(d-a)^2+4bc$.  What do you mean by "it"?  The slope of the convergence line?

Comment: The quantity under the square root sign in your calculation of $\lambda$

Comment: @WillJagy Got it.  I double checked my work and found the error.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be the two eigenvalues of $A$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ the corresponding eigenvectors. Then we can diagonalize $A$ such that $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ where $\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $S=[v_1,v_2]$. Note that we can write 
$$x_n=A^nx_0=(S\Lambda S^{-1})^nx_0=S\Lambda^nS^{-1}x_0$$ 
Now, $S^{-1}x_0$ changes the basis of $x_0$ from the standard basis to that consisting of the eigenvectors. Let us say $S^{-1}x_0=\begin{bmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\Lambda^n S^{-1}x_0=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1^nc_1 \\ \lambda_2^nc_2\end{bmatrix}$ and so $$A^nx_0=S\Lambda^n S^{-1}x_0=\lambda_1^nc_1v_1+\lambda_2^nc_2v_2$$
Can you tell what happens to $A^nx_0$ when $n\to\infty$ from here?

**Edit:** To elaborate some more: WLOG let $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|$. Then $A^nx_0\sim\lambda_1^nc_1v_1$. The slope of a vector $w$ is the same as the slope of the vector $kw,\forall k\ne0,k\in\mathbb{R}$ so the slope of $A^nx_0$ approaches the slope of $v_1$.

**Edit 2:** This is of course assuming $x_0^Tv_1\ne0$ because if $x_0^Tv_1=0$ then $c_1=0$.

Comment: By initial appearance, $A^nx_0 \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ unless |$\lambda_1$| <1 and |$\lambda_2$| < 1.   But how does this connect to the slope $m$?

Comment: @TylerMurphy see edit